# Silverstripe changing the class of a DataList

Tags: orm, silverstripe

I have a Holder class that returns a DataList of type BaseClass. The objects are really SearchClass objects. How do I convert the DataList so that I can filter by the SearchClass fields.

```
class SearchClass extends BaseClass(){
    public static $db = array('myField' => 'Int');
}

abstract class Holder{
    abstract protected function myList();
}

$holder = new ConcreteHolder();
$holder->myList()->filter('myField',1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more time here's the solution I came up with.

```
public function convert($list){
    $ids = $list->filter('ClassName', 'SearchClass')->getIDList();
    return SearchClass::get->byIDs($ids);
}
```

Comment: return $list->filter('ClassName', 'SearchClass'); // would have sufficed

Comment: Datalists work on a specific class database table. so the Datalist only knows about BaseClass attributes.

Comment: DataList includes all subclasses also.

Comment: If you run 
`Debug::dump(SearchClass::get()->filter('myField',1)->sql());` youll see that it will do a JOIN for the tables. You are doing an unnecessary query now. Unless you are handling the dataobjects from the start also in a weird way as the query you did so @micmania1 answer is the one you should pick.

Comment: Also i'm not sure about the purpose of the of the 
$holder = new ConcreteHolder(); bit. You can use ModelAdmin to manage the dataobjects and then just directly filter the dataobjects with SearchClass::get()->filter('baseField', 'aValue') rather than getting them through the  new ConcreteHolder();. Probably the is a reason for that but just pointing out :)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is:

```
class Holder extends DataObject {
    public function myList(){
        return SearchClass::get()->filter('baseField', 'aValue');
    }
}
```